# Java heap space with GSON

Tags: java, eclipse, gson, heap-memory

I'm creating some big JSON file using GSON to create custom JSON from GTFS (Google Transit). The problem is when I'm converting from my object class to JSON:

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String rutasJSON = gson.toJson(my_object);
```

It gives this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:544)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:387)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:402)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:353)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:337)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:105)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:565)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:520)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:500)
    at transporte.main(transporte.java:152)
```

I've tried to change eclipse.ini from this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

To this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How were you able to resolve the issue for a single object ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of tweaking the JVM it might be a good idea to use a streaming API instead of loading the whole json into memory before writing it.

have a look at the 'Mixed Writes Example' on https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not tweak `eclipse.ini` because that affects the JVM settings of the Eclipse program. I suppose your program starts a different JVM and you should set the memory settings of that JVM. See the "Run configuration" of your program in Eclipse.

Comment: I've already done that in VM arguments inside `Run configuration` putting: -Xms256M -Xmx512M

Comment: Try to add more. This is the most probable way to go

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the JVM that is running eclipse (controlled through `eclipse.ini`) is running out of memory but the separate JVM that is used for running your program is running out of memory.

If you are using a 1.5 client JVM, I think the standard maximum memory setting (`-Xmx`) is 64 MB.

In order to change the maximum memory, do the following:

- right-click "Run As..." or "Debug As..." and
- then "Run Configurations" or "Debug Configurations"
- then click the arguments tab
- then add `-Xmx512m` into the "VM arguments"
- then click run

If you're still running out of memory, increase the amount.

Answer (score 1):

I think your JVM running in eclipse is out of memory.so you must increase size for JVM.To change the VM for Eclipse you can change the amount of the MV from **Windows> Preferences> Java>** Installed JREs from there select the JRE and click edit, then write in the Default VM Arguments: to -Xmx1024M or any other amount of memory.

Refer this link you got an [idea](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html#How%20to%20solve%20java.lang.OutOfMemoryError%3a%20Java%20heap%20space).